# .DS_Store not excluded when put in gitignore

Tags: java, bitbucket, gitignore

I have a Java application where a .DS_Store file is present within the directories, but I have added ".DS_Store" to a line within gitignore that should exclude this file when pushing to bitbucket. However, on bitbucket I can still see the .DS_Store file - does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: You need to delete it from git first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is on bitbucket, you included it in a previous commit before you ignored it. You need to delete it (in a commit) and push that commit to bitbucket.